# $(document.ready) not evoked when form submitted to same page

Tags: php, jquery, submit

I have developed a multi-field form with a search facility. I have used popup window for displaying search results and user may select one of those results to edit and get filled in the parent window. Also I need to pass two variables between jQuery and PHP to the page for formatting. I have done it all. The only problem I am facing is when form is submitted after closing the popup window, it is not evoking its `$(document).ready()` and `$(window).load()` methods.

**The code I used on popup window:**

```
$("#modify").on('click', function () {
    var $ele = $('input[name="rad_selected"]:checked');

    if ($ele.length) {
        var $tds = $ele.closest('tr').find('td');
        var id = $tds.eq(2).text();
        var requestor = $tds.eq(3).text();
        // and so on..
        //alert(id);            
        //alert(requestor);
        opener.document.frm_beneficiary.task.value =  "modify";
        opener.document.frm_beneficiary.role.value = 10;
        opener.document.frm_beneficiary.benid2.value =  trim(id);
        opener.document.frm_beneficiary.searchName2.value =  trim(requestor);
        self.close();
    }
    else {
        alert("Select a record you want to edit.");
    }
});
```

This passes all the four values to hidden fields of the form successfully. Even the search is also working fine.

**The code on parent window:**

```
function submitForm()
{

    with(document.frm_beneficiary)
    {
        alert("submitform");
        action = "frm_ben_entry.php";
        submit();
    }
}
```

This `submitForm()` function is called after the popup is closed.

NOTE : `submitForm()` is called many a times in the page itself and evokes both the `$(document).ready()` and `$(window).load()` methods when used without popup in between. I am not getting what I am missing.

I just want these two jquery methods to be evoked when the page is reloaded. Thanks.

**EDIT:**
This code is added to call the `submitForm()` function after the popup is closed

```
window.onunload = function (e) {
    opener.submitForm(); //or
    //opener.document.getElementById('someid').innerHTML = 'update content of parent window';
};
```

Comment: $("#modify").off('click'); add the line on before the on statement

Comment: $("#modify").off('click');
    $("#modify").on('click', function () {
    //function
    }

is not working for me.

Comment: ok use the line into the on statement.

Comment: @SudharsanSri any details? how to use it into ON statement?

Comment: i need to trigger the `.ready();` event...